# Determine which textview should be cut off

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

In a relativelayout I am using the code below. If the total width is too high `tvProgress` should be cut off. The problem is that I don't know how to determine which view should be cut off. The current code lets `list_lib_episodes_watched_total` cut off. How can I determine that `tvProgress` is cut off instead?

```
...
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProgress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/list_lib_et_episodes_watched"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_lib_cover"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Progress:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/list_lib_et_episodes_watched"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_lib_status_spinner"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvProgress"
    android:hint="0"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxEms="4"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:text="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_lib_episodes_watched_total"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/list_lib_et_episodes_watched"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_lib_episodes_watched_increase"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_lib_et_episodes_watched"
    android:lines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="/0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#707070" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/list_lib_episodes_watched_increase"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_lib_et_episodes_watched"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_lib_et_episodes_watched"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_transparant"
    android:contentDescription="Increase by 1"
    android:minWidth="60dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_increase" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cut any view?? It is wrap_content so you cannot determine like that. Put everything inside  . Then nothing will be cut. You can scroll and see everything.

ScrollView is like this:

```
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

---
---
---

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This isn't the method I want. It's a quite advanced view and making this scrollable will definitely not benefit the user experience. Thanks for helping me anyway.